# react-native iOS native module: calling method that activates network indicator asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am writing a native module that calls functions from a closed source framework binary that I don't have access to. It makes blocking network calls and activates the network indicator. I want to be able to run it in the background asyncronously, It kind of works out of the box, but when I do that I get this warning/error and the call stalls a bit:

`Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]`

If I put it on the main queue using the following code in my In my RN Module, the calls block everything until they complete.

```
- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
  return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}
```

Here is an example of a method exposed to JS:

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(createSession,
                 userIDtoken:(NSString *)userIDtoken
                 createSessionWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    Boolean connected = [_networkController startSession:userIDtoken isTest:true];
    NSString *success = @"session created";
    if (connected){
      resolve(success);
    } else {
      NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ConnectionError" code:1 userInfo:nil];
      reject(@"session_creation_failed", @"Cannot create sessions", error);
    }
}
```

`_networkController startSession` should run in the background without throwing the warning/error and without blocking the main thread. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by extending UIApplication.

Create a `main.h` and declare a class `MyApplication` that extends `UIApplication`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyApplication : UIApplication
@end
```

Then implement it with an override of `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` in `main.m` and pass it to `UIApplicationMain`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "main.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyApplication
- (void)setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:(BOOL)setVisible {
  // do nothing or something
}
@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(
                             argc,
                             argv,
                             NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]),
                             NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make `UIKit` API calls on a background thread as it is not thread-safe.

You can remove the RN module `methodQueue` setup so your module's method will get called once again on a background thread and will not block the main thread. Whenever you need to make a call to `[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]` (or any other method that requires the main queue), you can dispatch it to the main thread, for example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
});
```

In case you need to resolve the promise only after setting the activity indicator, you can also put your calls to resolve/reject inside the same block after changing the activity indicator visibility.

Comment: The problem is that `setNetworkIndicator` is run inside the closed source function. This function runs a network call that takes ~5 seconds to return. This entire process has to be be wrapped in `dispatch...(dispatch...^{}))` in my code. If that function did not call `setNetworkIndicator` I could run it on a background thread, but because it does, iOS won't let me. I have no way to change that function. Is this impossible?

Comment: I see. I probably missed the part where the actual calls to `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` are performed by the closed source framework. You'd expect that the library will provide a way to make this run asynchronously. In case they don't support it, you could use method swizzling as a last resort - you would replace `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` with your own version and force it to get called on the main thread as necessary

Comment: So it's possible to overwrite the native implementation of `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` that the closed source framework runs; so potentially I could just make it do nothing? Obviously this seems sketchy, but it might be my only option until I can potentially get the library maintainers to modify their code for my purposes. If this is the case, please modify your answer with some more detail and I will accept it.

Comment: actually, I just found another solution. I extended `UIApplication` and overwrote `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` in main.m and fed it to `UIApplicationMain()` see my answer.